# How to launch Windows Terminal as external terminal for debugging a Python file?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, windows-terminal

Windows 10 
VS Code 1.49.0

My `settings.json`:

```json
"python.pythonPath": "C:\\Python38",
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\PowerShell Core\\pwsh.exe",
"terminal.explorerKind": "external",
// NOTE: I have a space in my username
"terminal.external.windowsExec": "C:\\Users\\USER NAME\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps\\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_8wekyb3d8bbwe\\wt.exe",
```

My `launch.json` located in the root of my workspaces `.vscode` directory:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "externalTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to launch the current Python file in Windows Terminal when debugging.  With my settings as is, I receive the following error (modified my username in the image and I have a space in my username):

[image]

But if I place extra escaped double quotes(`\"`) in `settings.json` for `terminal.external.windowsExec`:

```json
"terminal.external.windowsExec": "\"C:\\Users\\USER NAME\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps\\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_8wekyb3d8bbwe\\wt.exe\"",
```

I receive a different error message:

[image]

I would appreciate some help on getting Windows Terminal to launch in VS Code when I run debug on a Python file.

#### SIDE NOTE

For `Ctrl + Shift + C` usage in VS Code, if I don't add the the extra escaped double quotes to the path of `wt.exe` for `terminal.external.windowsExec`, then Windows Terminal launches properly.

If I add the escaped double quotes, I get the same error as the first attach image stating `Windows cannot find 'C:\Users\USER '`.

Comment: I see two potential issues.  1) Do you really have a user on your system named `USER NAME`?  If not, do you expect those characters in the path you show to be replaced by something else?  2) I think the space in `USER NAME` is indeed causing you a problem.  If it is really what you want there, or you want another name there with a space in it, I think you need to escape the space, like: `"\"C:\\Users\\USER\ NAME\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps\\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_8wekyb3d8bbwe\\wt.exe\""`

Comment: I modified my actual username to `USER NAME`, but my real username on my system does have a space in-between.  Also, I mentioned in my post I did include the escaped double quotes, yet I was getting the error.

Comment: So did you try escaping the space?

Comment: Did you even read my post?  I put all of that information in there.

Comment: I did, and I just did again.  I don't see anywhere that you put a backslash in front of the space between `USER` and `NAME`.  I'm sorry if I'm missing it somehow.

Comment: Do you mean this part: `"terminal.external.windowsExec": "\"C:\\Users\\USER NAME\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps\\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_8wekyb3d8bbwe\\wt.exe\"",`?

Comment: yes, that's what I mean

Comment: That's what I tried, and stated it in my post.  I get the second error message.

Answer (score 0):

`launch.json` should have `"terminal": "external"` or `"console": "externalTerminal"`

`settings.json` should have

```
"terminal.external.windowsExec": "wt cmd",
```

or

```
"terminal.external.windowsExec": "wt -p \"Command Prompt\"  --title \"VSCode External Terminal\" cmd",
```

the `\"Command Prompt\"` is your `windows terminal`'s profile name you want to use.

https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/ifou0y/using_new_windows_terminal_as_external_terminal/gaqrjt8?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3